# AJAX PHP MYSQL Update / Edit Records (jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

What I'm wanting to do is use jQuery/Ajax to update rows in an outputted table using php and mysql pdo. I'm having issues actually posting the data and then returning it.

If anyone can help me get this working, it will be greatly appreciated!! Thank you!

Here is the form I'm using in the users.php page.
(Please note this is within an echo statement, that's why the variables are '.$var.').

The form below is iterated for each row.

**Users.php**

```
<form action="users_manage" method="post" id="submit_form" name="users_manage">
 <input hidden id="uid" name="uid" value="' . $id . '" />
 <input hidden id="first_name" name="first_name" value="' . $first_name . '" />
 <input hidden id="last_name" name="last_name" value="' . $last_name . '" />
 <input hidden id="contact_email" name="contact_email" value="' . $contact_email . '" />
 <button id="usertp" name="user_type" value="1" type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
 <button id="usertp" name="user_type" value="2" type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> </button>
</form>
```

**Script on users.php**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#usertp").click(function () {

            var user_type = $('#usertp').val();

            var uid = $('#uid').val();

            var first_name = $('#first_name').val();

            var last_name = $('#last_name').val();

            var contact_email = $('#contact_email').val();

            if(user_type=='') {
                alert("Please Fill All Fields");
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "users_manage.php",
                    data: {
                        user_type: user_type,
                        uid: uid,
                        first_name: first_name,

                        contact_email: contact_email
                    },
                    success: function (msg) {
                        // alert(msg);
                        $('#result').html(msg);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**users_manage.php**

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test', 'test_user', '1234');

$uid = $_POST['uid'];
//$user_type = $_POST['user_type'];

$user_type = 0;

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id=:uid");
$stmt->execute( [ ':uid' => $uid] );
$num1 = $stmt->rowCount(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

if($num1 == 1){
  $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET user_type=:user_type WHERE id=:uid");
  $stmt->execute([ ':uid' => $uid, ':user_type' => $user_type]);
}
```

Comment: ID's are meant to be unique. Use a class. as are name attributes.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The problem is not getting the IDs. It is getting the IDs jut fine I believe as when I try to update a record it posts the data to the address bar. Thanks though

Comment: He's not saying that's the cause of your issue, just stating they are meant to be unique. `$('#usertp').val()` in your code will always give you `1` since your IDs are not unique.

Comment: @mark.hch how would I go about fixing that?

Comment: Plus, `rowCount()` won't work here. You need to use `fetch()` and doing `if($num1 >= 1)`

Comment: Use classes, as @Fred-ii- suggested, like `class='usertp'`, then change your click listener's selector, and use `this` to obtain the value: `$('.usertp').click(function(){ var user_type = $(this).val(); /* code here */ });`

Comment: @Fred-ii- @mark.hch I did this but it doesn't return any value:
`$('.usertp').click(function(){
                var user_type = $(this).val();
                var uid = $(this).val();`

Comment: did you change the rowCount() to what I suggested and the conditional statement?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeh it's now: `$num1 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM); if($num1 >= 1){`

Comment: drop the `PDO::FETCH_NUM` just use `fetch()` and check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: also remove `method="post"` from the form, you're already declaring post in your ajax.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've tried both but it still is yet to work, how can I dump the error if its trying to use ajax?

Comment: you can check your logs if you have access to any. and check your console.

Comment: @Fred-ii- so it's calling this because there's not data being submitted and I've done everything you have said. `if(user_type=='') {
                    alert("Please Fill All Fields");
                }` It displays that alert

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112235/discussion-between-harvey-connor-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 0):

@Harvey Connor Can you please check below code. please change value in your form.

Users.php

```
    <form action="" method="post" id="submit_form" name="users_manage">
    <input hidden id="uid" name="uid" value="1" />
    <input hidden id="first_name" name="first_name" value="firstname" />
    <input hidden id="last_name" name="last_name" value="lastname" />
    <input hidden id="contact_email" name="contact_email" value="test@gmail.com" />
    <input id="usertp" name="user_type" value="1" type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-sm btn-success" />
    <input id="usertp" name="user_type" value="2" type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-sm btn-danger" />
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

Script on users.php

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#usertp").click(function () {
    var user_type       = $('#usertp').val();
    if(user_type=='') {
    alert("Please Fill All Fields");
    return false;
    } else {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "users_manage.php",
    data: $("#submit_form").serialize(),
    success: function (msg) {
    $('#result').html(msg);
    return false;
    },
    error: function () {
    alert('error');
    return false;
    }
    });
    }
    return false;
    });
    });
    </script>


users_manage.php


   <?php

    //$db   = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
    $db     = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test', 'test_user', '1234');
    $uid    = $_POST['uid'];
    //$user_type = $_POST['user_type'];

    $user_type  = 0;
    $stmt       = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id=:uid");
    $stmt->execute( [ ':uid' => $uid] );
    $num1       = $stmt->rowCount(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

    if($num1 == 1){
      $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET user_type=:user_type WHERE id=:uid");
      $stmt->execute([ ':uid' => $uid, ':user_type' => $user_type]);
      $result = "User successfully updated.";
    } else {
      $result = "User update fail.";
    }
    echo $result;
```